# Reading a file line delimited by a comma using fgets and sscanf

Tags: c, file

EDIT(Way more information):
This part of the code initializes the structure. It is global.

```
struct csvVars
{
    int timeStamp[500];
    int xAccel[500];
    int yAccel[500];
    int zAccel[500];
    int xGyro[500];
    int yGyro[500];
    int zGyro[500];
};

struct csvVars *userVars;
```

This is my function which finds the users condition. From using the printf I can determine the program crashes at the sscanf part.

```
void userCondition()
{
    FILE *csvFile = fopen("C:\\user.csv", "r");
    if (csvFile == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file ! \n");
        return;
    }


    char line[100];
    int i = 0, j;
    double average;
    double xAver = 0, yAver = 0, zAver = 0;


    //skips first line
    fgets (line, 100, csvFile);

    fgets (line, 100, csvFile);

    while(!feof(csvFile))
    {
        printf("111");
        sscanf(line, "%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d", &userVars->timeStamp[i], &userVars->xAccel[i], &userVars->yAccel[i], &userVars->zAccel[i], &userVars->xGyro[i], &userVars->yGyro[i], &userVars->zGyro[i]);
        fgets (line, 100, csvFile);
        i++;
    }

    for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        xAver += userVars->xAccel[j];
        yAver += userVars->yAccel[j];
        zAver += userVars->zAccel[j];
    }

    xAver = xAver/(i+1);
    yAver = yAver/(i+1);
    zAver = zAver/(i+1);

    printf("%lf\n", xAver);
    printf("%lf\n", yAver);
    printf("%lf\n", zAver);

    fclose(csvFile);
}
```

This is a sample file line:

```
11201,2614,2441,2300,1854,978,1370
```

SOLUTION:

```
void userCondition()
{
    FILE *csvFile = fopen("C:\\user.csv", "r");
    char line[200];
    int i = 0, j;
    double xAver = 0, yAver = 0, zAver = 0;

    struct csvVars userVars;

    //skips first line
    fgets (line, 100, csvFile);

    fgets (line, 100, csvFile);

    while(!feof(csvFile))
    {
        sscanf(line, "%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d", &userVars.timeStamp[i], &userVars.xAccel[i], &userVars.yAccel[i], &userVars.zAccel[i], &userVars.xGyro[i], &userVars.yGyro[i], &userVars.zGyro[i]);
        i++;
        fgets (line, 100, csvFile);
    }

    for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        xAver += userVars.xAccel[j];
        yAver += userVars.yAccel[j];
        zAver += userVars.zAccel[j];
    }

    xAver = xAver/(i+1);
    yAver = yAver/(i+1);
    zAver = zAver/(i+1);

    printf("%lf\n", xAver);
    printf("%lf\n", yAver);
    printf("%lf\n", zAver);

    fclose(csvFile);
}
```

Comment: What if there's other errors reading from the file? Your code will not detect that and blissfully continue with, in essence, an infinite loop. Instead do e.g. `while (fgets(...) != NULL)`

Comment: And to extend the question from @user3121023, how are they *initialized*? And also please show the definition of whatever structure `userVars` is.

Comment: Be sure to check the return value from `sscanf()` before using the values read.

Comment: Of course, insure `i < 500` and `userVars` is allocated memory.

Comment: Updated the OP, as for the file it's declared:FILE *csvFile =        fopen("C:\\user.csv", "r");
 if (csvFile == NULL)
 {
  printf("Error opening file ! \n");
  return;
 }

Comment: The major flaw in posted code is well identified by [@paul](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29352374/2410359).   If you have additional trouble, It is likely in unposted code.  You could accept that and start a new question or add to this one.

Comment: I updated the OP once more with all relevant code.

Comment: If I change the userVars to make it not a pointer the code fails at the scanf.

Comment: This worked and I added the solution to the OP.

Answer (score 3):

**Step 1.** Change:

```
sscanf(line, "%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d", userVars->timeStamp[i], userVars->xAccel[i], userVars->yAccel[i], userVars->zAccel[i], userVars->xGyro[i], userVars->yGyro[i], userVars->zGyro[i]);
```

to:

```
sscanf(line, "%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d", &userVars->timeStamp[i], &userVars->xAccel[i], &userVars->yAccel[i], &userVars->zAccel[i], &userVars->xGyro[i], userVars->yGyro[i], &userVars->zGyro[i]);
```

**Step 2.** Find out how to turn on compiler warnings (e.g. `gcc -Wall`), turn them on, and pay attention to anything the compiler tells you. Never compile without warnings enabled. This would have saved you a lot of time with this particular error, and will continue to save you a lot of time in the future.

Comment: Did you fix all your compiler warnings ? If so, then it's probably time to learn how to use your debugger.

Comment: @raz789 You never initialize `userVars` so it contains garbage and points to random memory. That is why you're still crashing.

Comment: Add this before the loop and your code should work: `userVars = malloc(sizeof(*userVars));`